# POP method linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I've implemented a pop method in Java I would use it for delimiter matching, though it leaves one element in the list.

```
    public int length(){
    Node current = this.head;
    int length = 0;
        while(current != null){
            current = current.getNextNode();
            length += 1;
        }
    return length;
}

public char pop(){
    Node current = this.head;
    Node lastN = this.last;

    for(int i = 0; i < length() - 2; i++){
        current = current.getNextNode();
    }
    current.setNextNode(null);
    this.last = current;

    return lastN.getBracket();
}
```

How do I pop the first element if length is >= 1?, or any suggestion for improving my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use java.util.LinkedList.

With `addFirst()`, `addLast()`, `size()`, `removeFirst()` and `removeLast()` you are covered.

Alternatively, check this [delimiter check example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/StackExampleDelimiterMatching.htm) for another way.

In you code, you miss the "initial" or "last element" case, which is special. You should check for the case of `this.head == this.last`; case where you should return the last element and clean up the list.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to do it for practice purposes, also doing it manually is really important and kinda makes you think.

Comment: just added an idea.

Comment: Did you check the "initial" case idea?

Answer (score 0):

Why moving through the list elements in the loop? How about instead of that:

```
if (this.head != null)
{
    char val = this.head.getBracket();
    this.head = this.head.getNextNode();
}
```

This snippet will drop the first element and set head to point to the second element. I guess JVM will delete old `head`. If the list is circular, then also set `last` to point to the new head.